# What are \xHEX characters and is there a table for them?

Tags: java, python, c, string, generics

When reading a textfile, I read these characters, when printed out to console it outputs blanks or �:

```
['\x80', '\xc3', '\x94', '\x99', '\x98','\x9d', '\x9c', '\xa9', '\xa6', '\xe2']
```

What are these \xHEX characters? Is there a link to the table to lookup these characters?

**SOLVED:**

it's not an `ascii` textfile, it was a unicode `utf8` file. That was why I was unable to get correct the characters.

For Java:

```
import java.io.*
File infile = new File('\home\foo\bar.txt');
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(infile), "UTF8"));
while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
System.out.println(str);
}
```

if `system.out.println` complains try:

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
out.println(str);
```

For Python, simply:

```
import codecs
infile = '\home\foo\bar.txt'
reader = codecs.open(infile,'r','urf8')
for l in reader:
  print ln
```

Comment: Have a look at [encodings](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/index.html)

Comment: Have you even tried to do some research yourself? A simple google for any of those characters will show you they are `unicode` and then it is simply a matter of searching for "unicode conversion chart"

Comment: when i try to print it as `unicode`, it gives `'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0`...

Comment: Unicode is a character set, not an encoding in itself.  UTF-8 is the most common encoding used for Unicode, but 0x80 isn't valid UTF-8 (and there's no Unicode character with that character value either).  What's the source of this data, and are the examples in your question taken from an actual file?

Comment: It is not UTF-8 encoded. You'll have to figure out the *correct* codec for that file. Without more context, that is impossible for us to do, a few hex bytes not a textual context make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link to all unicode characters:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

Also, if you are using Eclipse, make sure your project "Text File Encoding" is set to UTF-8.

**Project->properties->resources->Text File Encoding.**

I had similar problem with cyrillic characters :)

Answer (score 1):

I may suggest that your text file is not really a "text file". 
The first two bytes form the unicode 'À' character. The rest, I guess, are non-printable characters. It seems that your file has a raw sequence of bytes, that don't have to be characters.

You've got a table [here](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/).

Answer (score 1):

Please note that java encodes characters in an unicode format (\u...) . It is possible to display the numbers '80', but not its character's presentation '\x80' to the console.

For a list, please refer to ascii characters list, [like this one](http://donsnotes.com/tech/charsets/ascii.html)